# Getting rust-analyzer error while running a substrate based chain

Tags: substrate-node-template, rust

[image]

## My problem

### Running `cargo build` does not give any error in terminal but `rust-analyzer` of Visual studio code gives me 85 errors and 8 warnings.

I followed the installation guide from the substrate docs. I can compile the project from the terminal and run it, and when I run it, it produces blocks as expected.

1. I can compile the `main branch` of `substrate-developer-node-template` perfectly and **opening that from Visual Studio Code does not give me any error**.
2. Errors in Visual Studio Code only shows up when I want to work with [cord](https://github.com/dhiway/cord.git).

### My Device

I'm using M1 MacBook Pro and the project I'm mentioning is [Cord](https://github.com/dhiway/cord.git). I'm running the `dev-0.8.0` branch.

### My Configurations

`rust-toolchain.toml` file in the project directory

```
[toolchain]
channel = "nightly-2022-11-15"
components = [ "rustfmt", "clippy" ]
targets = [ "wasm32-unknown-unknown" ]
```

My Visual Studio Code `settings.json`

```json
{
  "telemetry.telemetryLevel": "off",
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "editor.formatOnType": true,
  "editor.formatOnPaste": true,
  "workbench.sideBar.location": "right",
  "workbench.activityBar.visible": true,
  "editor.fontSize": 26,
  "debug.console.fontSize": 20,
  "terminal.integrated.fontSize": 20,
  "editor.suggestFontSize": 20,
  "editor.wordWrap": "on",
  "workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",
  "workbench.colorTheme": "Everforest Dark",
  "editor.fontFamily": "'Hack Nerd Font', monospace",
  "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "comments": "#10d77e"
  },
  "javascript.suggest.includeAutomaticOptionalChainCompletions": false,
  "extensions.autoUpdate": "onlyEnabledExtensions",
  "editor.quickSuggestions": {
    "other": true,
    "comments": false,
    "strings": false
  },
  "editor.autoClosingBrackets": "always",
  "javascript.updateImportsOnFileMove.enabled": "always",
  "emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "javascript": "javascriptreact"
  },
  "emmet.triggerExpansionOnTab": true,
  "emmet.showExpandedAbbreviation": "inMarkupAndStylesheetFilesOnly",
  "editor.linkedEditing": true,
  "editor.fontLigatures": true,
  "emmet.showSuggestionsAsSnippets": true,
  "editor.snippetSuggestions": "top",
  "emmet.showAbbreviationSuggestions": true,
  "explorer.confirmDelete": false,
  "workbench.startupEditor": "none",
  "editor.multiCursorModifier": "ctrlCmd",
  "editor.codeLens": true,
  "extensions.ignoreRecommendations": true,
  "editor.tabCompletion": "onlySnippets",
  "editor.detectIndentation": true,
  "editor.guides.bracketPairs": "active",
  "projectManager.sortList": "Name",
  "window.commandCenter": true,
  "javascript.preferences.quoteStyle": "double",
  "typescript.preferences.quoteStyle": "double",
  "[markdown]": {
    "editor.unicodeHighlight.ambiguousCharacters": false,
    "editor.unicodeHighlight.invisibleCharacters": false,
    "editor.wordWrap": "on",
    "editor.quickSuggestions": {
      "comments": "off",
      "strings": "off",
      "other": "off"
    },
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "yzhang.markdown-all-in-one"
  },
  "sql-formatter.dialect": "sql",
  "sql-formatter.uppercase": true,
  "sql-formatter.linesBetweenQueries": 2,
  "explorer.confirmDragAndDrop": false,
  // Begin Rust configs
  "[rust]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "rust-lang.rust-analyzer",
    "editor.formatOnSave": true
  },
  // macOS settings
  "rust-analyzer.cargo.target": "aarch64-apple-darwin",
  "rust-analyzer.diagnostics.disabled": [
    "unresolved-proc-macro",
    "incorrect-try-target",
    "unresolved-method"
  ],
  "rust-analyzer.server.extraEnv": {
    "CHALK_OVERFLOW_DEPTH": "2000"
  }
}
```

Running `rustup show` from the `home` directory (not in the project directory), gives me

```sh
rustup show
Default host: aarch64-apple-darwin
rustup home:  /Users/roynrishingha/.rustup

installed toolchains
--------------------

nightly-2022-11-15-aarch64-apple-darwin
nightly-aarch64-apple-darwin (default)

installed targets for active toolchain
--------------------------------------

aarch64-apple-darwin
wasm32-unknown-unknown

active toolchain
----------------

nightly-aarch64-apple-darwin (default)
rustc 1.70.0-nightly (cf7ada217 2023-04-03)
```

Running `rustup show` from the project directory

```sh
rustup show
Default host: aarch64-apple-darwin
rustup home:  /Users/roynrishingha/.rustup

installed toolchains
--------------------

nightly-2022-11-15-aarch64-apple-darwin
nightly-aarch64-apple-darwin (default)

installed targets for active toolchain
--------------------------------------

aarch64-apple-darwin
wasm32-unknown-unknown

active toolchain
----------------

nightly-2022-11-15-aarch64-apple-darwin (overridden by '/Users/roynrishingha/work/cord/rust-toolchain.toml')
rustc 1.67.0-nightly (96ddd32c4 2022-11-14)
```

Running from the project directory

```sh
cargo -V && rustc -V
cargo 1.67.0-nightly (a3dfea71c 2022-11-11)
rustc 1.67.0-nightly (96ddd32c4 2022-11-14)
```

Running from the home directory

```sh
cargo -V && rustc -V
cargo 1.70.0-nightly (0e474cfd7 2023-03-31)
rustc 1.70.0-nightly (cf7ada217 2023-04-03)
```

### What I have tried

1. I deleted Rust using `rustup self uninstall` and did a fresh install with only nightly toolchain. But it did not help.
2. I tried to freshly clone the project repo into a different directory and build from there. But it did not help.
3. Uninstalled Visual Studio Code and Re-installed. For some reason new installation automatically loaded the old configs.
4. Uninstalled `rust-analyzer` from Visual Studio Code extensions. But same issue.

### NOTE

Other developers are able to compile and run on Visual Studio Code (this project) perfectly. Only I'm stuck! **It doesn't work on my machine**.

### REQUEST

**Kindly help me out to get unstack**

Comment: When you run `cargo build`, was there any error? If not than there is no problem with the code might be some problem with rust-analyzer, I also face this sometimes.

Comment: `cargo build` and rust-analyzer worked fine for me on branch `dev-0.8.0`. Here is the version of rust I am using on my M1. And I am using rust-analyzer `v0.4.1462`

Comment: Hi @Bruno thanks for your effort. I had rust-analyzer v0.3.1463, but I just switched into `rust-analyzer version: 0.4.1462-standalone (e87154017 2023-04-04)` (the pre-release version). But the issue still persists .

Comment: @ShubhamGupta how do you solve this type of issues ? Can you show any light?

Comment: Are you using any other VS code extensions that could be interfering like caching?

Comment: @Bruno after the fresh installation of vscode, I turned off sync and only installed rust-analyzer version v0.4 (same as yours). Nothing else installed. 
`settings.json` now looks like this:
```json
{
  "rust-analyzer.cargo.target": "aarch64-apple-darwin",
  "rust-analyzer.diagnostics.disabled": [
    "unresolved-proc-macro",
    "incorrect-try-target",
    "unresolved-method"
  ],
  "rust-analyzer.server.extraEnv": {
    "CHALK_OVERFLOW_DEPTH": "2000"
  },
  "workbench.startupEditor": "none",
}
```

Comment: @Bruno I thought it a problem of either rust-analyzer or Visual Studio Code. So I installed [Zed](https://zed.dev) editor. It automatically downloaded rust-analyzer LSP and I also get the same 85 errors and 8 warnings. So most probably it's rust-analyzer. I'm probably missing some config!

Comment: Yea looks like it is an issue with the extension. Perhaps look [here](https://rust-analyzer.github.io/manual.html#toolchain) and [here](https://rust-analyzer.github.io/manual.html#troubleshooting). You could also try changing the `rust-analyzer.check.targets` to an x86 nightly:`nightly-x86_64-apple-darwin` and see if that works